# Calling exec, getting NameError though the name is defined

Tags: python

I have a file named `file.py` containing the following script:

```
def b():
    print("b") 
def proc():
    print("this is main")
    b()    
proc()
```

And I have another file named `caller.py`, which contains this script:

```
text = open('file.py').read()
exec(text)
```

When I run it, I get the expected output:

```
this is main 

b
```

However, if I change `caller.py` to this:

```
def main():
    text = open('file.py').read()
    exec(text)
main()
```

I get the following error:

```
this is main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./caller.py", line 7, in <module>
    main()
  File "./caller.py", line 5, in main
    exec(text)
  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 8, in main
NameError: global name 'b' is not defined
```

How is function `b()` getting lost?  It looks to me like I'm not violating any scope rules.  I need to make something similar to the second version of `caller.py` work.

Comment: I'm curious why you want to do this rather than importing `file.py`. Anything imported automatically executes all code not under a `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause, and you can also use functions explicitly like `file.proc` or `file.b`. Although your question is interesting just from the mystery angle of what you've pointed out - perhaps that's why you posted rather than looking for a workaround.

Comment: Because it's not calling the same thing all the time--my program reads arbitrary scripts from a database table and executes them on an as-needed basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exec(text)` executes `text` in the current scope, but modifying that scope (as `def b` does via the implied assignment) is undefined.

The fix is simple:

```
def main():
    text = open('file.py').read()
    exec(text, {})
```

This causes `text` to run in an empty *global* scope (augmented with the default `__builtins` object), the same way as in a regular Python file.

For details, see the [`exec` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec).  It also warns that modifying the default local scope (which is implied when not specifying any arguments besides `text`) is unsound:

> The default *locals* act as described for function `locals()` below: modifications to the default locals dictionary should not be attempted. Pass an explicit *locals* dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on *locals* after function `exec()` returns.

Comment: Pasting the code into `main` actually wouldn't produce the same error; `def b()` would define `b` locally inside `main`, but all attempts to access `b` would be inside `main` too, so things would be fine. The difference with `exec` is that trying to assign variables (`def` counts as assignment) is undefined behavior with the default locals, and functions defined with `exec` don't see locals in the `exec` scope.

Comment: Thanks, I incorporated this.

Answer (score 1):

Would it work for you if you imported and called the function instead?

myfile.py

```
def b():
    print("b") 

def proc():
    print("this is main")
    b()
```

caller.py

```
import myfile

myfile.proc()
```

Comment: No, see comment above.